# Docker compose build | Image after pull does not work / is empty

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, laravel-sail

I have a laravel app.

I used laravel sail to generate the docker-compose.yml file.
Sail also created a Dockerfile in `./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.0`
I see this also in the .yml file.

When I run on my local maschine `docker-compose up` it will create an image and run a container.
This container works fine.

Now I use `docker-compose build` to create an image which I want to share with a colleague.
Docker will create the image successfully. I push it to HUB via Docker Desktop and my colleague can pull it.

But the pulled image does not work. When I observe the container through the CLI the app code is not even there. It looks like an empty image. Same also happens when I pull it on my local maschine.

Something gets messed up when I push the image to docker. Does anyone have an idea whats happening?

As per request here are the steps to reproduce:

Add laravel sail to an existing laravel project (You do not need the execute this if you create a new laravel project, which is laravel 8+):

```
composer require laravel/sail --dev
```

Then follow the laravel sail guide and call:

```
php artisan sail:install
```

The above call will generate a `docker-compose.yml`

Now you can run a container with `docker-compose up`.

This will create an image and run a container.
If you want to push this image to the HUB, then the issues appear.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.app:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.0
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: dockeruser/feedback_app:1.5
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to include a [mcve]?  In particular, does the Dockerfile actually `COPY` code into the image?  (I've seen a couple of recent Laravel SO questions that have an "image" which is basically the unmodified `php:fpm` image, and inject the code via a bind mount, so the image doesn't actually contain the application and can't usefully be pushed.)

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for the reply. You already mention a possible issue. I will check this out. I also tried to add simple instructions on how to reproduce the issue.

Comment: In the `docker-compose.yml` file you show, try deleting the `volumes:`; those inject local files into the image, and you won't have them available remotely.  Does the application still work?